# SQL - Convert BIGINT(20) to datetime datatype

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion, mysql-workbench

In mysql workbench, I have an id column in my table with bigint as its data type:

```
id BIGINT(20)
```

This column holds the datetime as a bigint.

To clarify more, the column holds a value such as:

```
20190529230339
```

I need to convert it into a datetime data type to be presented as:

```
2019-05-29 23:03:39
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `STR_TO_DATE`, after first casting the bigint number to text:

```
SELECT
    field,
    STR_TO_DATE(CAST(field AS CHAR(14)), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s') AS field_datetime
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

STR_TO_DATE will do the trick:

SELECT CONVERT(STR_TO_DATE('20130101 1130','%Y%m%d %h%i'),DATETIME);

I used Convert instead of Cast

2013-01-01 11:30:00